# Exposing C++ functions, that return pointer using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I want to expose the following C++ function to Python using Boost.Python:

```
int* test1() {
    return new int(42);
}

// Now exposing the function with Boost.Python

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtest1)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("test1", test1);
}
```

When I try to compile this library the error occurs due to (it's my guess) Boost.Python don't know, how to convert int* to PyObject.

I think what needs to be done is to define conversion structure, something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct int_ptr_to_python
{
   static PyObject* convert(int* i_ptr)
   {
        return i_ptr;
   }
};
```

And pass it to the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE declaration:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtest1)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("test1", test1);
    to_python_converter<int*, int_ptr_to_python<int*> >();
}
```

But it also doesn't work. And I can't find any information about how the functions, that return pointers should be handled.

Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, one cannot directly expose a function returning `int*` with Boost.Python, as there is no  meaningful corresponding type in Python given integers are immutable.

- If the goal is to return a number to Python, then return `int` by value.  This may require using an auxiliary function to adapt legacy APIs.
- If the goal is to return a pointer to an object allocated with a new-expression, then the object must be a class or union, and the function must be exposed with specific policies to indicate ownership responsabilities.

---

Rather than present the final solution immediately, I would like to take the time to step through the compiler errors.  With Boost.Python, sometimes pre-C++11 static assertions are used to provide instructions in the compiler messages.  Unfortunately, it can be a bit difficult to find them amongst the heavy templates.

The following code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int* make_int() { return new int(42); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("make_int", &make_int);
}
```

produces the following relevant output in clang, with the important details accentuated in bold:

```
.../boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:102:98: error:
  no member named 'get_pytype' in 'boost::python::detail::
    specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<int*>'
  ...create_result_converter((PyObject*)0, (ResultConverter *)0, 
                             (ResultConverter *)0).g...
```

Boost.Python is informing us that a [`boost::python::return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html) needs to be specified for functions returning `int*`.  There are various models of [ResultConverterGenerators](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html#result_converter_generators).  Often times the policies are used to control the ownership or lifetime semantics of the returned object.  As the function in the original code is returning a new pointer directly to Python, the [`boost::python::manage_new_object`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/manage_new_object.html) is appropriate if the caller is expected to take responsibility for deleting the object.

Specifying a policy for object management still fails:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int* make_int() { return new int(42); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("make_int", &make_int,
    python::return_value_policy<python::manage_new_object>());
}
```

produces the following relevant output:

```
.../boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:27:9:
  error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::or_<is_class<T>, is_union<T> >));
```

In this case, Boost.Python is informing us that the object returned from a function with a `managed_new_object` ResultConverterGenerator must be either a `class` or `union`.  For an `int*`, the most appropriate solution is to return the `int` by value when passing through the Boost.Python layer.  However, for completeness, below demonstrates:

- Using an auxiliary function to adapt a legacy API.
- How to limit the creation of a user defined type with a factory function that returns pointers.

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// Legacy API.
int* make_int() { return new int(42); }

/// Auxiliary function that adapts the legacy API to Python.
int py_make_int()
{
  std::auto_ptr<int> ptr(make_int());
  return *ptr;
}

/// Auxiliary class that adapts the legacy API to Python.
class holder
  : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
  holder()
    : value_(make_int())
  {}

  int get_value() const     { return *value_; }
  void set_value(int value) { *value_ = value; }

private:
  std::auto_ptr<int> value_;
};

/// Factory function for the holder class.
holder* make_holder()
{
  return new holder();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("make_int", &py_make_int);

  python::class_<holder, boost::noncopyable>("Holder", python::no_init)
    .add_property("value",
      python::make_function(&holder::get_value),
      python::make_function(&holder::set_value))
    ;

  python::def("make_holder", &make_holder,
    python::return_value_policy<python::manage_new_object>());
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(42 == example.make_int())
>>> holder = example.Holder()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python
>>> holder = example.make_holder()
>>> assert(42 == holder.value)
>>> holder.value *= 2
>>> assert(84 == holder.value)
```

Comment: your the only guy on the entire stack overflow that makes sense of this obfuscated system